# Recursive functions that rotate n elements of a list to left and right in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

The function has 1 parameter, an integer.
For example `rot-left(2 '(1 2 3 4 5))` should return `(3 4 5 1 2 )` and `rot-right(2 '(1 2 3 4 5))` should return `(5 4 1 2 3)`.

I've tried this... it doesn't work but what it's supposed to do is add the last n elements of a list to an empty list.

```
(defun rot_left (n l)
  (if (zerop n)
      '()
      (append (last l)
              rot-left ((- n 1) (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? On StackOverflow, we don't write code for you. We'll gladly help anyone who is stuck, but you should first try yourself. Besides, this was my homework at age 13.

Comment: I've tried this... it doesn't work but what it's supposed to do is add the last n elements of a list to an empty list. (defun rot_left(n l) (if(zerop n) '() (append (last l) rot-left((- n 1) (cdr l)))))

Comment: Now edit your question to include this, and anything else you've tried

Comment: Without actually formatting your code, you will have a hard time to get the syntax correct.

Comment: For googlers and Common Lisp, see `alexandria:rotate`.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a solution assuming that, if the function `rot-right` should rotate the elements of the list from right to left, `(rot-right 2 '(1 2 3 4 5))` should produce `(4 5 1 2 3)` and not `(5 4 1 2 3)`.

Then, assuming that this interpretation is correct, the functions can be written only by means of primitive operators in Common Lisp, without the use of iteration or recursion:

```
(defun rot-left(n l)
  (append (nthcdr n l) (butlast l (- (length l) n))))

(defun rot-right(n l)
  (rot-left (- (length l) n) l))

(defvar a '(1 2 3 4 5))

(rot-left 2 a)   ;  produces (3 4 5 1 2)
(rot-right 2 a)  ;  produces (4 5 1 2 3)
```

Comment: The function should be recursive. What does the butlast operator do? I'm new to list so I really don't know too much.

Comment: this is a really cool solution but noticed it fails with an obscure error in sbcl and abcl in if n > length of l, another solution could be something like

`(defun rotate-left (n l)
  (let* ((len* (length l))
         (n* (mod n len*)))
    (append (nthcdr n* l) (butlast l (- (length l) n*)))))`

EDIT: damned formatting